# Google Play Crawler results - save to CSV

Tags: python

I made a simple crawler that extracts CSV file with google play packages like `com.viber.voip` and go to the full link like `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viber.voip&hl=en`.

Then it crawles the title, publisher, downloads etc and stores into a list.
The problem is, when Im trying to save the results into CSV file it throws me an error if Im exporting using pandas to_csv. Or throws UnicodeError when it finds some unknown characters. I tried to add .encode or .decode but it doesnt help. Can someone assist please?

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import csv

def searcher(bundles):
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url+bundles+post_url).read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    title_app = soup.title.get_text()
    publisher_name = soup.find('a', {'class':'document-subtitle primary'}).get_text()
    category = soup.find('a', {'class':'document-subtitle category'}).get_text()
    ratings = soup.find('meta', {'itemprop':'ratingValue'}).get('content')
    reviews = soup.find('span', {'class':'reviews-num'}).get_text()
    downloads = soup.find('div', {'itemprop':'numDownloads'}).get_text()
    updated_last_time = soup.find('div', {'class':'content'}).get_text()
    text = (bundles, title_app, publisher_name, category, ratings, reviews, downloads, updated_last_time)
    return (text)

def store(crawled_data):
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    labels = ['bundles', 'title_app', 'publisher_name', 'category', 'ratings', 'reviews', 'downloads', 'updated_last_time']
    writer.writerow(labels)
    df = pd.DataFrame(crawled_data)
    for row in df:
        if row != None:
            writer.writerow(row)

base_url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id='
post_url = '&hl=en'
crawled_data = []
crawled_packages = 0

with open('links.csv', 'r') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    urls = df['URLs']
    for bundles in urls:
        if bundles != None:
            aaa = searcher(bundles)
            print(crawled_packages)
            crawled_packages += 1
            if crawled_data != None:
                crawled_data.append(aaa)

store(crawled_data)
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Include in your question the input and the full traceback of the error message. At the moment, it sounds like you are talking about more than one problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `to_csv()` by specifying an output file to use. Also specify your column names whilst building the dataframe:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import csv

def searcher(bundles):
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url+bundles+post_url).read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    title_app = soup.title.get_text()

    publisher_name = soup.find('a', {'class':'document-subtitle primary'}).get_text(strip=True)
    category = soup.find('a', {'class':'document-subtitle category'}).get_text(strip=True)
    ratings = soup.find('meta', {'itemprop':'ratingValue'}).get('content')
    reviews = soup.find('span', {'class':'reviews-num'}).get_text(strip=True)
    downloads = soup.find('div', {'itemprop':'numDownloads'}).get_text(strip=True)
    updated_last_time = soup.find('div', {'class':'content'}).get_text(strip=True)
    return (bundles, title_app, publisher_name, category, ratings, reviews, downloads, updated_last_time)


def store(crawled_data):
    labels = ['bundles', 'title_app', 'publisher_name', 'category', 'ratings', 'reviews', 'downloads', 'updated_last_time']
    df = pd.DataFrame(crawled_data, columns=labels)
    df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)


base_url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id='
post_url = '&hl=en'
crawled_data = []
crawled_packages = 0

with open('links.csv', 'r') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    urls = df['URLs']
    for bundles in urls:
        if bundles != None:
            aaa = searcher(bundles)
            print(crawled_packages)
            crawled_packages += 1
            if crawled_data != None:
                crawled_data.append(aaa)

store(crawled_data)
```

This will give you an `output.csv` file containing:

```
bundles,title_app,publisher_name,category,ratings,reviews,downloads,updated_last_time
com.viber.voip,Viber Messenger - Android Apps on Google Play,Viber Media S.à r.l.,Communication,4.336112022399902,"11,016,404","500,000,000 - 1,000,000,000","March 15, 2018"
```